# Trouble with sentence structure and particles

Tags: grammar, words

I've been having a hard time understanding how to construct a sentence. If I were going to say something along the lines of: "Learning Japanese on your own is difficult." Would this be grammatically correct:
 自分で日本語を学ぶのは難しい。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「[自分]{じぶん}で[日本語]{にほんご}を[学]{まな}ぶのは[難]{むずか}しい。」 is nice and grammatical.

You could make it sound even more natural by changing 「自分」 to 「ひとり」 or 「自分ひとり」.

Furthermore, adult native speakers would use the word 「[独学]{どくがく}」 to mean "to study by oneself".  If you were a beginner, though, you would not need to know this word yet; **It can wait**.  One would say:

「独学で日本語を[勉強]{べんきょう}するのは難しい。」 or

「日本語を独学するのは難しい。」